# Control a vector if there is a specific element

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a method for controling a vector if there is altready a specific element or not. So I have a graph structure which looks like this:

```
struct graph {  
    std::vector <std::vector<int>> gr;
};
```

and then I have a method for adding an edge between the two vertices.

```
void add_edge(graph& g, int from, int to) {

        if  ( from >= 0 && to >= 0 && from < g.gr.size() && to < g.gr.size()) {
            g.gr[from].push_back(to);
        }

}
```

This method has to add a directed edge between the two vertices, controls if there is already a directed edge, if yes-does nothing. And it only can be called with existing nodes.
The main problem is that I don't know how to control if there is a directed edge or not. I tryed to use a `std::find(g.gr[from].begin,g.gr[from].end, to) != g.gr[from].end())` condition but it ended with an error.

```
FIRST ERROR Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error C3867 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::begin': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member DU2 c:\users\1\...\graph.hpp    81 
SECOND ERROR Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error C2672   'std::find': no matching overloaded function found  DU2 c:\users\1\..\graph.hpp 81
```

Comment: Can you specify the error in your question please. Best is to provide a [MCVE] demonstrating it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ FIRST Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C3867 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::begin': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member DU2 c:\users\1\...\graph.hpp 81                           SECOND Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2672 'std::find': no matching overloaded function found DU2 c:\users\1\..\graph.hpp 81

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Updated already

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `()` at the end of `g.gr[from].begin` and `g.gr[from].end` in `std::find`